# Android: run process or thread in a specific core

Tags: android, multithreading, cpu

Is there any way of creating a process or thread in a specific core in Android?

edited for more info: the idea is that having two cores, I would like to run 2 different processes or threads in 2 different cores. Specifically, what I want to do is use 100% of the CPU of the phone, no matter how many cores the phone has.

Comment: What do you mean by saying "in a specific core"? Thank you

Comment: add more description. not getting your situation(problem)

Comment: I'm afraid, this is controlled only by the OS, but can't say exactly.

Comment: edited. I have the guess that it is not possible to choose, but I would like to know if there is such an option. Otherwise, I do not know how to reach 100% of CPU if all the threads or processes are run in only one core.

Comment: News:
I created a small program with a service that creates two low priority threads. The threads are all the time in a while loop. 

When I run only one thread, I get 50% of CPU. When I run 2, I get 100%. Therefore, the OS runs one thread in each core. 

However, I have not found any way of choosing the core so far neither an explanation of how android manages multicore.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way of creating a process or thread in a specific core in Android?

No, sorry.

> the idea is that having two cores, I would like to run 2 different processes or threads in 2 different cores.

That is for the OS to decide, not you.

> Specifically, what I want to do is use 100% of the CPU of the phone, no matter how many cores the phone has.

No developer should have that as an objective, outside of benchmarking applications and the like.

Comment: "outside of benchmarking applications and the like.", which is my case. Thanks for the answer!